# Query writing issue in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Table_A:             Table_B:

Column_A             Column_A   Value  EmpId

A                    A          1      1
B                    B          2      1
C                    -          -      - 
D                    -          -      -
```

I have 2 tables as you can show above. I want to get all the records of **Table_A** related to the **EmpId**

**My Expected Result related to EmpId - 1:**

```
Column_A  Value  
A         1 
B         2
C         null
D         null
```

I have used the below query:

```
Select * from Table_A a left join Table_B b on a.Column_A = b.Column_B
```

The above query will give my expected result but it as you can see it is not filtered on the basis of EmployeeId. Can anyone help me. Thanks

**ANY QUICK HELP PLEASE**

Answer (score 2):

```
Select a.Column_A, b.Value 
from Table_A a 
left join Table_B b on a.Column_A = b.Column_B  
and b.EmpID = 1
```

Should give you the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply filters of EmpID, then just add where clause,

```
Select * from Table_A a 
left join Table_B b on a.Column_A = b.Column_B  
where b.EmpId = 1
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer already provided by Stuart?

Comment: not too much except, syntax. But adding condition in where clause is good idea, if user wants to add more conditions for filtering including columns of any table from SQL Script.But for this ans only Stuart solution is also perfect. I just have added ans by keeping future requirements in mind.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that by adding the criteria to the WHERE clause is that you've transformed the resultset to be an INNER JOIN instead of a LEFT OUTER JOIN.  In other words, only rows that have a b.EmpID of 1 will be returned, which is NOT what the expected results show (one row per row in table A, nulls for non-matched in table b).

Comment: sounds very correct! Thanks! But please go through question again "My Expected Result related to EmpId - 1:"